# CFFORM Format="HTML" does not display anything when a record contains a backslash \

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid, cfform

I have a Windows Server 2003 R2 running ColdFusion 9 Standard.  We are using CFFORM and CFGRID to display information returned from a query.  Whenever a record has a \ in any field in the entire query record set, the grid and data do not show up at all.

In this particular form, the field is not even mapped with cfgridcolumn nor used but the field was part of the query.  Even though it was not used in the CFGRID, just the presence of a backslash in any field in the query breaks the cfgrid.

I was able to fix this particular error by not calling that unused field in the database, however, I would really like to know what causes this and if there is a way to fix it without worrying about fields containing a backslash.

Here is a video capture of the process:  http://screencast.com/t/0NUlwlFMtk6t

Comment: Can you please post some stand-alone code that demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: You're gonna need to better identify your problem. The code at https://gist.github.com/4406374 demonstrates to me that there is no intrinsic issue with slashes in grid data, so you've not yet tied-down what the problem with your code actually is. It might help to read at least a section of a blog article I wrote about how to track down code problems, then ask for help on them. http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/need-help-know-how-to-ask-for-it.html#identifyTheProblem. Don't worry about the irritation I express at the top of the article, that is not aimed at you ;-)

Comment: Well, one main difference is the result sets are actually coming from a database (MySQL) query.  That could be a clue.

Comment: Be that as it may, it's for you to provide us with a repro case that demonstrates what you're talking about, so we can try to help you. That said, the code ain't gonna know where the data came from, it just sees "data". So that it's from MySQL or a text file or user input will almost certainly be neither here nor there. You can verify this yourself by serialising & deserialising the recordset then gridding it. The results will be the same.